# Ticket Endpoint of keycloak giving 400

Tags: python, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am working on sharing of resources between multiple users using keycloak. After creating a resource when I request for ticket permission I get 400, but the issue is these 400 is not constant some time the response is 200 and sharing is perfect but there some cases I get 400 response. 400 is bad request the payload I am sending are correct every time. These 400 are not consistent that's why I find it very difficult to debug it.

```
def _owner_action_scopes(owner_token, resource_id, scope, requester, granted):
    

    ticket_url = f"{server_internal_url}realms/{realm_name}/authz/protection/permission/ticket"
    
          data = {"resource": resource_id,
            "requester": requester,
            "granted": granted,
            "scopeName": scope}

    headers = {}

    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    headers["Host"] = kc_host
    status = requests.post(ticket_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), verify=VERIFY)

    return status
```

Comment: Is there any other error messages? Or just a status code?

Comment: 400 can be because of any parameter - it can be because of headers or data as well, do you think your header values are always available and as per need ? Better to print the header details , and see what goes for a case of 400

Comment: @ex4 its just 400 no error message.

Comment: @kris Headers are same in every case I have checked it while debuging

Comment: You probably have to access server log to see what is going on. This information isn't enough to troubleshoot.

Comment: I debug it again, the error is "Permission Already Exist"